# How can I create an Entity Relationship diagram (ER) For BigQuery Tables/ Views

Tags: google-bigquery, entity-relationship

I have some complex BigQuery views that nest each other. I would like to map them in an ER diagram so they are easier to visualize. I can do t his manually but prefer a system that can create the mapping automatically.

Are there any tools that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not know official google tool that provides such a feature from google side. Most of the diagram tools works like retrieving the schema information from google BigQuery and paste it on its services to have an image of it. On the web, there are some tools like [dbschema](https://dbschema.com/database-designer/GoogleBigQuery.html), [dataedo](https://dataedo.com/tutorials/create-diagram-for-google-big-query-database), [quickdatabasediagrams](https://www.quickdatabasediagrams.com/) to count some. Even small guides from know pages like this post [how-to-create-an-entity-relationship-diagram-erd-for-bigquery](https://medium.com/@donny.chen.ai/how-to-create-an-entity-relationship-diagram-erd-for-bigquery-a1e66cc24225) from medium site.

As mention on google official documentation [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tutorials) about data visualization, It can be achieved by using [pandas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas), [notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter), [data studio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio) although it requires some effort to have something as you envision on your question.

If you have ideas to have that feature implemented on google BigQuery you can also open a `feature request` on google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685).